# Why is the distance matrix I upload into R not symmetric?

Tags: r, distance, qiime

I am trying to upload a distance matrix for a PCoA plot produced by the qiime2 pathway into R for data transformation. I can't seem to attach the file here, but here is an example of what the file looks like:

[image: sample distance matrix]

The distance matrix is symmetrical in qiime, so the issue should lie within R. I imported the dataset using `dm <- read.csv(file = "dm.csv", header = FALSE, row.names = 1)` in R.

When I test to see if the distance matrix is symmetrical using `isSymmetric.matrix(dm)`, the output is 'FALSE'. Any guidance as to how I would get a symmetrical distcance matrix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It _looks_ symmetric to the eye, I wonder if this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272

Comment: Did you convert it to `matrix` class? `read.csv` returns a data frame, not a matrix. I wonder if that's why you're calling `isSymmetric.matrix(dm)` instead of just `isSymmetric(dm)`. If it is a `matrix`, you shouldn't need to specify. Try `isSymmetric(as.matrix(dm))`

Comment: Check the CSV. You might have lost precision when saving the data as a CSV. E.g., I know that Excel only saves digits that are being displayed as a CSV. The screenshot show different numbers of digits for different columns.